# Set the value of the default data-bind options

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Lets assume that we have the following data-binding

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
        optionsText: 'countryName',
        value: selectedCountry,
        optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

I want to set the default value of optionsCaption.

(the value of `selectedCountry` when the user has "choose.." selected)

https://jsfiddle.net/3z2zzy0b/2/

Comment: what you try to ask in the question what is your issue?

Comment: I need to set the value of the select box when nothing is selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `optionsCaption` selection cannot be assigned an arbitrary option value (out of the box, anyway). A couple options to consider, some more roundabout than others:

1. Just adding another option into your countries array, e.g.:

   ```
   self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
           'Choose...',
           'United States',
           'Mexico',
           'Canada'
   ]);
   ```

   and then having some logic to check for when `selectedCountry == 'Choose...'`.
2. Similar to 1, turn your array into an array of objects:

   ```
   self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
           { text: 'Choose...', value: 'MY_DEFAULT' },
           { text: 'United States' value: 'United States' },
           { text: 'Mexico', value: 'Mexico' },
           { text: 'Canada', value: 'Canada' }
   ]);
   ```

   and bind as:

   ```html
   <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
           value: selectedCountry,
           optionsText: text,
           optionsValue: value">
   </select>
   ```
3. If you don't want that non-country element in your array (and you probably don't), you could get around it with an optionsAfterRender:

   ```html
   <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
           value: selectedCountry,
           optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
           optionsAfterRender: function(item, value) {
                   item.value = value || 'MY_DEFAULT';
           }">
   </select>
   ```

   This particular example will set any blank value to 'MY_DEFAULT'. You could also inspect `item` for text == 'Choose...'.

Comment: Markdown tip: if you use 8 spaces in front of code it will be a code block part of that list item. That way you don't need to use backtick-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default value, the use the `value` of the options.

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
    value: selectedCountry()">
</select>
```

Now the United States will be set from the options.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3z2zzy0b/3/

Comment: right, but I want there to be a "nothing selected" option still available

Comment: If you dont any thing to be selected simply remove the `optionsCaption`  and provide empty string to it.